# (Python 3.3) Can not figure out why function creates infinite loop when value gets to 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, infinite-loop

I'm working on a program that simulates a vending machine. For some this section of my code creates an infinite loop, I cant quite figure out why. I ran it through python tutor to see where my problem was, it seems that when my variable price_remaining = 5 it will sometimes not go through the elif statement. I'm not entirely sure what would trigger it one way or another.  I'm going to copy and paste what I entered in to python tutor in hopes that someone can explain based on that.
EDIT: I just checked through python tutor some more, it appears to only occur when I have a 
value for price_remaining ending with a 5. For example 2.05,0.05, 1.15, etc.

```
price_remaining = 2.55
price_remaining = price_remaining * 100
q_stock = 25
q_returned = -0
d_stock = 25
d_returned = 0
n_stock = 25
n_returned = 0
while price_remaining > 0:
    if price_remaining >=25 and q_stock > 0:
        price_remaining = price_remaining - 25
        q_stock = q_stock - 1
        q_returned = q_returned + 1
    elif price_remaining >=10 and d_stock > 0:
        price_remaining = price_remaining - 10
        d_stock = d_stock - 1
        d_returned = d_returned + 1
    elif price_remaining >=5 and n_stock > 0:
        price_remaining = price_remaining -5
        n_stock = n_stock - 1
        n_returned = n_returned + 1

print( q_returned)
print( d_returned)
print( n_returned
```

)

Comment: If an infinite loop is occuring, the condition `price_remaining > 0` continues to be true but none of the `if` conditions are True (or they'd continue to decrement price_remaining.) Why don't you add some print statements to the loop (I hate debuggers); `print price_remaining` at least just after the while loop.

Comment: I checked though and found that it was a float, so never quite 5. Thank you for the advice on the checks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I add the line

```
print(repr(price_remaining), repr(n_stock))
```

at the start of your `while` loop, the code produces

```
254.99999999999997 25
229.99999999999997 25
204.99999999999997 25
179.99999999999997 25
154.99999999999997 25
129.99999999999997 25
104.99999999999997 25
79.99999999999997 25
54.99999999999997 25
29.99999999999997 25
4.999999999999972 25
4.999999999999972 25
4.999999999999972 25
[.. forever ..]
```

Because of how floating point numbers work (see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) for a reminder), you can't always perfectly represent each possible number, hence all the 9s.

In any case, once `price_remaining < 5`, even if it's only less by a tiny amount, your code doesn't have any `if` branch which triggers.

Comment: So just the initial multiplication yields a mutant number, which carries throughout. That's actually pretty unfortunate :)

Comment: I'm sorry I can not upvote you for your help, but if it makes any difference I really appreciate it!